# How to change verbatim text to Consolas?

Tags: fonts, listings, verbatim, inconsolata

How to change the verbatim text so that a zero shows up with a slash across it?  I would like to know if the verbatim text can be changed to say Consolas?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\begin{document}
I wanted to make the table appear like a ``programming" type text:
\begin{verbatim}
-----------------
10  1   0.3 2
20  2   0.9 5
30  3   3   8
40  4   6   9
50  5   8   10
-----------------
\end{verbatim}

%\lstinputlisting{table.txt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{inconsolata}` but this will change the `\ttfamily` completely

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Hmmm. I see that you already wrote the `inconsolata` option in your comment, I added it to my answer after OP required a pdflatex option (initially I provided a xelatex approach). Do you want to provide the `inconsolata` answer? I can edit mine to suppress this part.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: No, it's alright. `inconsolata` will change the complete document font of `\ttfamily`, which is not wanted (perhaps?). I've not found out the real fontname for `\fontfamily` so far. (\fontfamily{zi4r}\selectfont` doesn't work in `basicstyle`, so your answer is an answer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\fontfamily{zi4}\selectfont` seems to work (and returning to `cmtt` as `\ttdefault`, if desired).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Strange, I got the usual `cmtt` in the listing

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For xelatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Consolas}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
10   1    0.3  2
20   2    0.9  5
30   3    3    8
40   4    6    9
50   5    8    10
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\newfontfamily{\ttconsolas}{Consolas}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttconsolas,
}
```

if you just want to change the mono font for the listings.

For pdflatex, load the `inconsolata` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{inconsolata}


\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
10   1    0.3  2
20   2    0.9  5
30   3    3    8
40   4    6    9
50   5    8    10
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Or,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{inconsolata}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\fontfamily{zi4}\selectfont,
}
\renewcommand*{\ttdefault}{cmtt}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
10   1    0.3  2
20   2    0.9  5
30   3    3    8
40   4    6    9
50   5    8    10
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

just for listings and the default monospaced font for the rest of the document.

Comment: Is there also an alternative for pdflatex?

Comment: @Joe Yes, there is. See my updated answer.