# PDFTex: text is not auto-column-fit inside longtable after given \texttt command

Tags: pdftex, longtable, inconsolata

I recently post a question about how to change a specific text's font-family [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/585175/can-i-change-font-family-only-for-some-text-in-longtable).

I found a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271279/how-to-change-verbatim-text-to-consolas) (and also from my recent post comment), using `\usepackage{inconsolata}`. This the doc's preamble about that package usage.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, onecolumn, oneside, final]{report}
\makeatother

\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\fontfamily{zi4}\selectfont,
}
\renewcommand*{\ttdefault}{cmtt}


\begin{document}
   blablalbalbalbalblablab
\end{document}
```

When I use it inside my longtable:

```
\begingroup
\setlength{\LTleft}{-20cm plus -1fill}
\setlength{\LTright}{\LTleft}
\begin{small}
    \begin{longtable}{|p{0.4cm}|p{3cm}|p{1.8cm}|p{1.8cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{3.55cm}|}
        \caption{Daftar \textit{Method} yang Digunakan} \label{tbl:pandas}\\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{No}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textit{\textbf{Method}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Input}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textit{\textbf{Output}}} & 
        \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Keterangan}}\\
        \cline{3-4}
        & & \textbf{Tipe} & \textbf{Variabel} & & \\
        \endfirsthead
        \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{\tablename~\thetable} Daftar \textit{Method} yang Digunakan (Lanjutan)}\\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{No}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textit{\textbf{Method}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Input}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textit{\textbf{Output}}} & 
        \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Keterangan}}\\
        \cline{3-4}
        & & \textbf{Tipe} & \textbf{Variabel} & & \\
        \endhead
        \hline
        1 & \texttt{librosa.core.spectrum.stft(x, n\_fft = window\_size, hop\_length = hop\_length, window=window)} 
        & Array & Data & - & Fungsi untuk membaca berkas audio yang akan diproses. Dalam penelitian ini, parameter \textit{filename} memiliki ekstensi wav. Fungsi ini menghasilkan keluaran berupa larik data audio dan \textit{sample rate}\\
        \hline
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{small}
\endgroup
```

The resulting table is like this:
[image]

Is there a way, by using `ttfamily` and make the that specific text auto-fit-column?

This is my desired output: (I made this using Ms.Word)
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! (i) please compose from your code fragments one, small and compilable document (ii) to preamble add missed packages (iii) what is `pd.DataFrameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee`?, it is not natural, hyphen able word, consequently it spill out of column (independent of used font family)

Comment: you loaded the inconsolata package then set the tt family back to the default cmtt so you are not really using the package at all. hyphenation is by default turned off in monospace fonts and you are using a fixed width `p` column. do you want the column to be wider (use `l` rather than `p{3cm}` or to allow line breaking in strings there are existing answers on this site

Comment: I pointed out in my code snippet that I do it on purpose to check whether it's fitting to the column or not. It is actualy only ```pd.DataFrame```, Pandas from Python library.

Comment: yes but it is better to give a real example, when typesetting python for example you might want to allow line breaking at `.` but not allow line breaking or hyphenatoon between letters, so your string of `eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee` is  not a representative of the actual problem

Comment: Ah, I see. That's my mistake. Thanks for pointing it out. So, how can I use the inconsolata package correctly after the modification? @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay. I will edit my question now.

Comment: just don't set ttfamily back but  the font is not really relevant to your line breaking question also you set up listings, do you want to show the python usoing lstinline (which does syntax highlighting an dcan allo line breaking) or simply use \texttt (no syntax highlighting monospace font)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I only want it to be auto-fit-column-text, just like the text in 'Keterangan' column. Should I also remove the ```listing```?

I've edited my question

Comment: in your desired image the situation is completeky different you are breaking at spaces and just setting ragged right in a _much_ wider column, that os completely different question to splitting long strings between non space letters in a very narrow column

Answer (score 1):

Your table declared many more columns than you appeared to be using, and judging by the desired output image that you added later you do not need to break strings between arbitrary letters, just normal breaking at white space.  Also you did not post a complete test document but putting your fragments together and removing unused packages and adding needed ones..

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, onecolumn, oneside, final]{report}


\usepackage{longtable,array,multirow}



\begin{document}


\begin{small}
\setlength{\LTleft}{-20cm plus -1fill}
\setlength{\LTright}{\LTleft}
    \begin{longtable}{|l|>{\ttfamily\raggedright\footnotesize}p{5.5cm}|
l|l|l|
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.55cm}|}
        \caption{Daftar \textit{Method} yang Digunakan} \label{tbl:pandas}\\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{No}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textit{\textbf{Method}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Input}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textit{\textbf{Output}}} & 
        \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Keterangan}}\\
        \cline{3-4}
        & & \textbf{Tipe} & \textbf{Variabel} & & \\
        \endfirsthead
        \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{\tablename~\thetable} Daftar \textit{Method} yang Digunakan (Lanjutan)}\\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{No}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textit{\textbf{Method}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textit{\textbf{Input}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textit{\textbf{Output}}} & 
        \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Keterangan}}\\
        \cline{3-4}
        & & \textbf{Tipe} & \textbf{Variabel} & & \\
        \endhead
        \hline
        1 & \texttt{librosa.core.spectrum.stft(x, n\_fft = window\_size, hop\_length = hop\_length, window=window)} 
        & Array & Data & - & Fungsi untuk membaca berkas audio yang akan diproses. Dalam penelitian ini, parameter \textit{filename} memiliki ekstensi wav. Fungsi ini menghasilkan keluaran berupa larik data audio dan \textit{sample rate}\\
        \hline
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{small}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem. Sorry, if I may ask a question again, what command should I add to make the text justified? I forgot to make them justified when using Ms.Word. I've edited the desired output image.

Comment: @DionisiusPratama they are justified by default but setting monospace font justified in narrow columns is essentially impossible (in any system as the constraints are not achievable)  that is why some words failed to fit. The whole point of this answer is to add `>{\raggedright}`  to _stop_ justification and to allow the text to fit.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you for the clarification